# Integrate PySpark with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm following this [site](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pyspark-installation-guide/) to install Jupyter Notebook, PySpark and integrate both.

When I needed to create the "Jupyter profile", I read that "Jupyter profiles" not longer exist. So I continue executing the following lines.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.ipython/kernels/pyspark

$ touch ~/.ipython/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json
```

I opened `kernel.json` and write the following:

```
{
 "display_name": "pySpark",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "IPython.kernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/Cellar/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/Cellar/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python:/usr/local/Cellar/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/usr/local/Cellar/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "pyspark-shell"
 }
}
```

The paths of Spark are correct.

But then, when I run `jupyter console --kernel pyspark` I get this output:

```
MacBook:~ Agus$ jupyter console --kernel pyspark
/usr/bin/python: No module named IPython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-console", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 595, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-113>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 137, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 110, in init_shell
    client=self.kernel_client,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 251, in __init__
    self.init_kernel_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 305, in init_kernel_info
    raise RuntimeError("Kernel didn't respond to kernel_info_request")
RuntimeError: Kernel didn't respond to kernel_info_request
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many ways to integrate pyspark with jupyter notebook.
 1.**Install [Apache Toree](https://toree.apache.org/docs/current/user/installation/)**.

```
  pip install jupyter
  pip install toree
  jupyter toree install --spark_home=path/to/your/spark_directory --interpreters=PySpark
```

you can check installation by

```
 jupyter kernelspec list
```

you will get an entry for toree pyspark kernel

```
  apache_toree_pyspark    /home/pauli/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_pyspark
```

Afterwards if you want, you can install other intepreters  like SparkR,Scala,SQL

```
 jupyter toree install --interpreters=Scala,SparkR,SQL
```

2.**Add these lines to bashrc**

```
  export SPARK_HOME=/path to /spark-2.2.0
  export PATH="$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin"    
  export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
  export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
```

type `pyspark` in terminal and it will open a jupyter notebook with sparkcontext initialized.

3. **Install `pyspark` only as a [python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark/2.1.1)**
   `pip install pyspark`

   Now you can import pyspark like another python package.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use findspark.  First create an environment variable:

```
export SPARK_HOME="{full path to Spark}"
```

And then install findspark:

```
pip install findspark
```

Then launch jupyter notebook and the following should work:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
```