# Initialize PySpark to predefine the SparkContext variable 'sc'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When using PySpark I'd like a SparkContext to be initialised (in yarn client mode) upon creation of a new notebook.

The following tutorials describe how to do this in past versions of ipython/jupyter < 4

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pyspark-installation-guide/

https://npatta01.github.io/2015/07/22/setting_up_pyspark/

I'm not quite sure how to achieve the same with notebook > 4 as noted in http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#since-jupyter-does-not-have-profiles-how-do-i-customize-it

I can manually create and configure a Sparkcontext but I don't want our analysts to have to worry about this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the missing profiles functionality in Jupyter also puzzled me in the past, albeit for a different reason - I wanted to be able to switch between different deep learning frameworks (Theano & TensorFlow) on demand; eventually I found the solution (described in a blog post of mine [here](https://www.nodalpoint.com/switch-keras-backend/)).

The fact is that, although there are not profiles in Jupyter,  the [startup files](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files) functionality for the **IPython** kernel is still there, and, since Pyspark employs this particular kernel, it can be used in your case.

So, provided that you already have a working Pyspark kernel for Jupyter, all you have to do is write a short initialization script `init_spark.py` as follows:

```python
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

and place it in the `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/` directory of your users.

You can confirm that now `sc` is already set after starting a Jupyter notebook:

```python
 In [1]: sc
 Out[1]:<pyspark.context.SparkContext at 0x7fcceb7c5fd0>

 In [2]: sc.version
 Out[2]: u'2.0.0'
```

A more disciplined way for integrating PySpark & Jupyter notebooks is described in my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824131/configuring-spark-to-work-with-jupyter-notebook-and-anaconda/47870277#47870277) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655575/cant-instantiate-spark-context-in-ipython/48744608#48744608).

A third way is to try Apache Toree (formerly Spark Kernel), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39181257/4685471) (haven't tested it though).

Comment: Thanks, this worked really nicely. I'm using the images from https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks as a base and have Toree working for Scala notebooks in yarn-client mode already. Re-reading the docs for Toree it says it supports Python interpreters too but I'm not sure why I should use Toree over the standard Python Kernel for PySpark. We have analysts that know both Scala + Python and we want to stay flexible

Comment: The profiles function of the ipython kernel is still there. It's pretty simple to create a kernel for each ipython profile just use the `argv` in `kernel.json` to set the profile, e.g. `"argv": [ "python3", "-m", "ipykernel", "--profile", "spark", "-f", "{connection_file}" ]`. I have a few ipython profiles that I want to keep separate for different purposes and a creating a kernel for each was the simplest way for me to achieve that.