# Connecting Jupyter notebook to Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ssh-tunnel

I have a machine with Hadoop and Spark installed. Below is my current environment.

python3.6

spark1.5.2

Hadoop 2.7.1.2.3.6.0-3796

I was trying to connect jupyter notebook to connect to spark by building up ipython kernel.

2 new files written.

1. /root/.ipython/profile_pyspark/ipython_notebook_config.py
2. /root/.ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py
3. /root/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json

kernel.json

```
{
    "display_name": "PySpark (Spark 2.0.0)",
    "language": "python",
    "argv": [
        "/root/anaconda3/bin/python3",
        "-m",
        "ipykernel",
        "--profile=pyspark"
    ],
    "env": {
        "CAPTURE_STANDARD_OUT": "true",
        "CAPTURE_STANDARD_ERR": "true",
        "SEND_EMPTY_OUTPUT": "false",
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON" : "/root/anaconda3/bin/python3",
        "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/"
    }
}
```

00-pyspark-setup.py

```
import os
import sys
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = "/root/anaconda3/bin/python"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client"
os.environ["PYLIB"] = os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] + "/python/lib"
spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
sys.path.insert(0, os.environ["PYLIB"] +"/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip")
sys.path.insert(0, os.environ["PYLIB"] +"/pyspark.zip")
exec(open(os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/pyspark/shell.py')).read())
```

ipython_notebook_config.py

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.port = 80
```

Then, when i run the following

```
jupyter notebook --profile=pyspark
```

The notebook is running well. Then, i change kernel to 'PySpark (Spark 2.0.0)', and it suppose to use the 'sc' spark context .  However, when i type 'sc', it does not shows anything.

So, since sc cannot be initiliazed, if i want to run the following, it failed!

```
nums = sc.parallelize(xrange(1000000))
```

Can anybody help me how to configure jupyter notebook to talk to Spark?

Comment: There seems to be a lot going on here. Try to focus your problem/question more. I suggest moving your Spark 2.0 problems to another question.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, python 3.6 isnt supported until version spark 2.1.1. See JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of issues with your question...

1) On top of the answer by Punskr above - Spark 1.5 [only works with Python 2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/); Python 3 support was introduced in [Spark 2.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/).

2) Even if you switch to Python 2 or [upgrade Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887227/how-to-upgrade-spark-to-newer-version/33914992#33914992), you will still need to import the relevant modules of Pyspark and initialize the `sc` variable manually in the notebook

3) You also seem to use an old version of Jupyter, since the profiles functionality is not available in Jupyter >= 4.

To initialise `sc` "automatically" in Jupyter >=4, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500744/initialize-pyspark-to-predefine-the-sparkcontext-variable-sc/43523771#43523771).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a few environment changes to have pyspark default ipython or a jupyter notebook.

Put the following in your `~/.bashrc`

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 ## for python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --no-browser --port=7000"
```

See: [pyspark on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark)

Next, run `source ~/.bashrc`

Then, when you launch `pyspark` (or with YARN) it will open up a server for you to connect to.

On a local terminal that has ssh capabilities, run

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8000:localhost:7000 <username>@<host>
```

If you're on Windows, I recommend [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Open up a web browser, and enter the address `localhost:8000` to tunnel into your notebook with Spark

Now some precautions, I've never tried this with Python 3 so this may or may not work for you. Regardless, you should really be using Python 2 on Spark 1.5. My company uses Spark 1.5 as well, as NO ONE uses Python 3 because of it.

### Update:

Per @desertnaut's comments, setting

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
```

may cause issues if the user ever needs to use `spark-submit`. A work around, if you want to have both notebooks and `spark-submit` available is to create two new environment variables. Here is an example of what you may create

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 ## for python3
export ipyspark='PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark'
export pynb='PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --no-browser --port=7000"'
```

where `ipyspark` and `pynb` are new commands on a bash terminal.

Comment: Setting `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to `ipython` or `jupyter` is a really *bad* practice, which can create serious problems downstream (e.g. [when trying `spark-submit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772280/spark-submit-cant-locate-local-file/46773025#46773025)); the recommended way is to [create an appropriate Jupyter kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824131/configuring-spark-to-work-with-jupyter-notebook-and-anaconda).

Comment: Yes, that's a common problem that can arise if you need to use `spark-submit`. At my previous job, we used it interactively so we seldom used `spark-submit`. However, a solution around this issue is to create a new variable, `ipyspark = PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark`. I'll explain this as an update to the answer.