# Can't instantiate Spark Context in iPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, ipython

I'm trying to set up a stand alone instance of spark locally on a mac and use the Python 3 API. To do this I've done the following,
1. I've downloaded and installed Scala and Spark.
2. I've set up the following environment variables,

```
#Scala
export SCALA_HOME=$HOME/scala/scala-2.12.4
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin

#Spark
export SPARK_HOME=$HOME/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin

#Jupyter Python
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

#Python
alias python="python3"
alias pip="pip3"

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

Now when I run the command

```
pyspark --master local[2]
```

And type sc on the notebook, I get the following,

```
SparkContext

Spark UI

Version
v2.2.1
Master
local[2]
AppName
PySparkShell
```

Clearly my SparkContext is not initialized. I'm expecting to see an initialized SparkContext object.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: _Clearly my SparkContext is not initialized_ - it is not clear to me at all. Please provide more details. Also check [Configuring Spark to work with Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47870277/8371915), which shows how to correctly configure Jupyter with Spark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as I have argued [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824131/configuring-spark-to-work-with-jupyter-notebook-and-anaconda/47870277#47870277), setting `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to `jupyter` (or `ipython`) is a really *bad* and plain wrong practice, which can lead to unforeseen outcomes downstream, such as when you [try to use `spark-submit` with the above settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772280/spark-submit-cant-locate-local-file/46773025#46773025)...

There is one and only one proper way to customize a Jupyter notebook in order to work with other languages (PySpark here), and this is the use of [Jupyter kernels](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html).

The first thing to do is run a `jupyter kernelspec list` command, to get the list of any already available kernels in your machine; here is the result in my case (Ubuntu):

```bash
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  caffe         /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/caffe
  ir            /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  pyspark       /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark
  pyspark2      /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark2
  tensorflow    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/tensorflow
```

The first kernel, `python2`, is the "default" one coming with IPython (there is a great chance of this being the only one present in your system); as for the rest, I have 2 more Python kernels (`caffe` & `tensorflow`), an R one (`ir`), and two PySpark kernels for use with Spark 1.6 and Spark 2.0 respectively.

The entries of the list above are directories, and each one contains one single file, named `kernel.json`. Let's see the contents of this file for my `pyspark2` kernel:

```bash
{
 "display_name": "PySpark (Spark 2.0)",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/opt/intel/intelpython27/bin/python2",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/home/ctsats/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/home/ctsats/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python:/home/ctsats/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/home/ctsats/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/opt/intel/intelpython27/bin/python2"
 }
}
```

Now, the easiest way for you would be to manually do the necessary changes (paths only) to my above shown kernel and save it in a new subfolder of the `.../jupyter/kernels` directory (that way, it should be visible if you run again a `jupyter kernelspec list` command). And if you think this approach is also a hack, well, I would agree with you, but it is the one recommended in the [Jupyter documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jupyter/latest/jupyter.pdf) (page 12):

> However, there isn’t a great way to modify the kernelspecs. One approach uses `jupyter kernelspec list` to find the `kernel.json` file and then modifies it, e.g. `kernels/python3/kernel.json`, by hand.

If you don't have already a `.../jupyter/kernels` folder, you can still install a new kernel using `jupyter kernelspec install` - haven't tried it, but have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython/44072803#44072803).

If you want to pass command-line arguments to PySpark, you should add the `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` setting under `env`; for example, here is the last line of my respective kernel file for Spark 1.6.0, where we still had to use the external spark-csv package for reading CSV files:

```bash
"PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 pyspark-shell"
```

Finally, don't forget to remove all the PySpark/Jupyter-related environment variables from your bash profile (leaving only `SPARK_HOME` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` should be OK).

Another possibility could be to use [Apache Toree](https://toree.apache.org/), but I haven't tried it myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) seams to say that environment variables are read from a certain file and not as shell environment variables.

> Certain Spark settings can be configured through environment variables, which are read from the conf/spark-env.sh script in the directory where Spark is installed